# Invalid <color> for given resource value

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I always get the following error when building:

```
Invalid <color> for given resource value.
Failed to compile values file.
```

My colors.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="Eins">#ffd700</color>
    <color name="Zwei">#000088</color>
    <color name="Drei">#fe0000</color>
    <color name="Vier">#8800ff</color>
    <color name="Funf">#008800</color>
    <color name="Sechs">#ff00ff</color>
    <color name="Sieben">#00ff00</color>
    <color name="Acht">#0088ff</color>
</resources>
```

I always called it with

```
resources.getColor(R.color.Sieben)
```

It worked the whole time, I didn't change anything, but suddenly it doesn't work anymore

I have copied the contents of the file several times into new files, the error is always in the same place

Comment: Why would you use Colors.xml instead colors.xml

Comment: I use colors.xml sorry

Comment: are you running on older Android versions like 4.4 ?? Try ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Sieben);

Comment: No from 8.0-11.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case there was double quote before @ in color resource declaring

```
<color name="some_color">"@color/text_01</color>
```

At the same time gradle warning pointed to other colors started "s", and didn't point to broken one. Fixing color resource resolved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

if you not see the icon from this color is something rung with this color code

Comment: I see the icon!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31116204)